# Relativity and mass increase

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, observers

Consider a long bridge which can marginally tolerate the weight of a car when it is parked on it. If this car has to go over this bridge with relativistic speed which increases its mass/weight above what the bridge can hold, what would happen? Will the bridge collapse (pedestrian view) or remain intact (driver view)?

Comment: What is the driver's view of the earth's mass from the rest frame of the car?

Comment: This effective mass is not a useful concept and we don't use it anymore.  It originates from the fact that mass is a form of energy and that energy is the time component of a 4-vector.

Comment: @ggcg Relativistic mass is like the corona virus.  It's does no one any good, but it will be with us for a very long time into the future.

Comment: Its already been over 100 years.  It's like ict

Comment: Terminology scolding aside, what is the answer to Q-Rius's question?

Comment: @Not_Einstein Yes, the car's effective mass on the bridge will be greater. But it's hard to give a physically realistic answer to this exact scenario! Just consider the wear on the tyres of a car traveling at 260,000 km per second... :)

Answer (score 2):

SPOILER ALERT: The following is probably not the answer you wanted, but as a recovering ex-engineer I can't help myself:

In practical terms, the bridge will not collapse, because the residence time of the relativistic car on the bridge will be insufficient for the applied stresses (the weight of the car) to propagate throughout the bridge structure (this occurs at the speed of sound in the bridge's girders, beams, etc.) before the car leaves the bridge and is gone.

Comment: Eg, if the car is moving at $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}c$, so $\gamma=2$, and the bridge is 260 km long, the car crosses the bridge in a millisecond. Of course, attaining such a speed in the atmosphere of the Earth is going to be rather tricky. ;)